# generate forecast using glm probit model

Tags: r, glm, forecasting

I am trying to generate a simple one-period forecast for a glm (probit regression) model, using the `forecast` command. But when running the below code I get the following message: `Error in as.data.frame(newdata) : argument "newdata" is missing, with no default`

```
#generate dataset with unknown value for last period dependent variable
data.set <- data.frame(date= seq(as.Date('2015-01-01'), by = 'days' , length = 100), 
                       replicate(100, sample(0:1,1)), runif(1e2),runif(1e2),runif(1e2))
colnames(data.set) <- c("date", "dv", "iv1", "iv2", "iv3")
data.set.ts <- xts(data.set[-1], order.by=data.set$date)
rm(data.set)
data.set.ts$dv[100] <- NA

#run glm probit model
PRmodel <- glm(dv ~ iv1 + iv2 + iv3, data = data.set.ts[-nrow(data.set.ts),], 
               family = binomial(link = "probit"))

#generate forecast for last period dv
iv_input <- xts(data.set.ts[, which(colnames(data.set.ts) %in% c("iv1" , "iv2" , "iv3"))], 
                order.by = index(data.set.ts))
start.date <- index(data.set.ts)[length(index(data.set.ts))]
fcastFn_output <- forecast(PRmodel, xreg=window(iv_input, start = start.date))
```

I have also tried using the `predict` command but R won't seem to generate a forecasted value for an observation if the actual is missing.

Comment: not near laptop so apologies if this is wrong, but I think `forecast` is designed for time series models, not glms.  My guess from the error is that it is ultimately being passed to `predict.glm` at which point the newdata argument (which specifies the input dataset of independant variables) doens't exist.  Try forming a dataset containing 101 dates instead of 100, then use `predict(PRmodel, newdata = data.set.2)` to get your predictions.  Would that work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code that generates a forecast should be along these lines

```
data.set <- data.frame(date= seq(as.Date('2015-01-01'), by = 'days' , length = 100), 
                       replicate(100, sample(0:1,1)), runif(1e2),runif(1e2),runif(1e2))
colnames(data.set) <- c("date", "dv", "iv1", "iv2", "iv3")
# Load the required package.
require(xts)
data.set.ts <- xts(data.set[-1], order.by=data.set$date)
rm(data.set)
data.set.ts$dv[100] <- NA

#run glm probit model
PRmodel <- glm(dv ~ iv1 + iv2 + iv3, data = data.set.ts[-nrow(data.set.ts),], 
               family = binomial(link = "probit"))

#generate forecast for last period dv
iv_input <- xts(data.set.ts[, which(colnames(data.set.ts) %in% c("iv1" , "iv2" , "iv3"))], 
                order.by = index(data.set.ts))
start.date <- index(data.set.ts)[length(index(data.set.ts))]
# Generate the forecast for 2015-04-10.
fcastFn_output <- predict(PRmodel, window(iv_input, start = start.date))
# Create a time series with all the forecasts.
fcastFn_all <- c(predict(PRmodel), fcastFn_output)
```

Hope this helps